# How to centralize a div using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an OrgChart control populates in the following form:

[image]

I have in each node Expand and Collapse functionality,
I wonder if you could help me with the steps to implement centeralization for the nods after expand or collapse them.

I would like to drag the horizontal scroll to centralize the expanded item and drag the vertical scroll to make the expanded item on the top. like the following image:

Note: I'm appreciate if I could do that with animation.
[image]

Any help!

Comment: Nice specification...where is your code now?

Comment: share some sample to get a clear picture of what u r doing

Comment: @Luca Fagioli: It's an ASP.Net control, and posting the code is useless. I need help in ideas, links instead of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ScrollTo plugin by Ariel Flesler should handle this perfectly.

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: Thanks, it's very good but doesn't support centralization directly, I have to calculate the specific point which I want to scroll to.

Comment: It does support percentages. This will center horizontally: `$('#scrollbox').scrollTo( {top:'0px',left:'50%'}, 800 );` This will center vertically: `$('#scrollbox').scrollTo( {top:'50%',left:'0px'}, 800 );`